# Extract location from HTTP socket

Tags: c, strings, http, socket

I have the following HTTP reply saved in a local file called `source.txt`:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
> Connection: close
> Content-length: 111
> Location: https://11.12.13.14:81/
> Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
>
> <html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=https://11.12.13.14:81/"></head><body></body></html>
> ```

Source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXBUFLEN 1024

char* getLocation(char* source)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(source, "Location:")+10;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    return res;
}

char* getData(char* source)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(source, "://")+3;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char source[MAXBUFLEN];
    char host[100];
    int port;
    FILE *fp = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), MAXBUFLEN, fp);
        if (newLen == 0) {
            fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
        } else {
            source[++newLen] = '\0';

//extraction code
            char* res = getLocation(source);
            printf("getLocation result: %s\n", res);
            if (strstr(res, "://"))
            {
                res = getData(source);
                printf("getData result: %s\n", res);
                if (strstr(res, ":"))
                {
                    sscanf(res, "%[^:]:%d[^/]", host, &port);
                    printf("host: %s | port: %d\n", host, port);
                }
                else
                    printf("delimiter not found\n");
            }
            else
                printf("no link\n");
//
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The program is working well, but it's very ugly.  Is there any way to improve the code to avoid doing so many operations?  I mean somehow merging the two functions, `getLocation()` and `getData()`.

Comment: What about at least a minimal description on what this functions should do?

Comment: you really need a description for that short code?

Comment: Please excuse, I do not need nothing, not even to read your posting. I just tried to kindly mention that an introduction to an issue, raises the chances of keeping a possible reader attracted.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getLocation` can be improved a little:

For a start, the call parameter should be `const` (although if you were happy
modifying the string you could avoid the memory allocation).

Moving on:

```
const char *p1 = strstr(source, "Location:")+10;
```

This is ok, except that `p1` is cryptic and it is better to avoid embedded constants such as 10. Since this is the length of "Location:", we can extract that:

```
#define LOC "Location:"
const char *loc = strstr(source, LOC) - 1 + sizeof LOC;
```

Note the -1 for the \0 at the end of LOC. But it is now uglier still.  And of
course it might fail, returning NULL.  So we need to protect the next line:

```
const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
```

in which you are looking for just one character; `strchr` is more appropriate and `eol` is a more descriptive name:

```
if (loc) {
    const char *eol = strchr(loc, '\n');
}
```

So next you get the length

```
size_t len = p2-p1;
```

which needs a cast to avoid a sign-conversion warning:

```
size_t len = (size_t) (eol - loc);
```

You allocate memory next:

```
char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
```

but you should omit the cast and note that sizeof(char) is 1 by definition,
so:

```
char *res = malloc(len + 1);
```

and of course allocation could also fail, so you must check before copying the
address into it.  You copy the address thus:

```
strncpy(res, p1, len);
res[len] = '\0';
```

but as you already know the length of the string, memcpy would be better, as
`strncpy` must check each char in the input string for \0

```
if (res) {
    memcpy(res, loc, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
}
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
static char* getLocation(const char* source)
{
#define LOC "Location:"
    size_t len = 0;
    char *eol = NULL;
    const char *loc = strstr(source, LOC) - 1 + sizeof LOC;
    if (loc) {
        eol = strchr(loc, '\n');
    }
    if (eol && loc) {
        len = (size_t) (eol - loc);
    }
    if (len) {
        char *res = malloc(len + 1);
        if (res) {
            memcpy(res, loc, len);
            res[len] = '\0';
        }
        return res;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Yes, string handling in C is ugly.

My conclusion from this ugliness is that another approach is needed.  Why not
modify the input string by putting a \0 at `eol` and returning `loc`?  Then
you could extract the address and port directly from that:

```
static char* getLocation(char* source)
{
#define LOC "Location:"
    char *loc = strstr(source, LOC) - 1 + sizeof LOC;
    if (loc) {
        char *eol = strchr(loc, '\n');
        if (eol) {
            *eol = '\0';
        }
    }
    return loc;
}
```